# How to use nameservers instead of A name record in bind

Tags: bind

Sorry if my question is wrong,

Suppose I have a domain called ab.com and I want to use nameservers instead of A record using bind DNS, how can I achieve it?

For example,

```
Namecheap Domain Panel:- ab.com nameservers set to 
ns1.abc.net - Personal Bind DNS
ns2.abc.net - Personal Bind DNS

Domain resolving to Bind DNS
```

Now I've got a web-hosting from godaddy.com with nameservers ns1.domain.com & ns2.domain.com, and instead of switching nameservers from Namecheap, I want to change it from Bind DNS.

```
BIND DNS Panel/Config:- ab.com nameservers set to 
ns1.domain.com - Godaddy DNS
ns2.domain.com - Godaddy DNS

Namecheap Domain >> resolving to Bind DNS > Bind >> resolving to Godaddy DNS > IP Address
```

How can I do that?

The domain from namecheap should resolve to MY BIND DNS (ns1.abc.net & ns2.abc.net) and from there it should resolve to GODADDY DNS.

This will help me work on all of my domains from one place.

Comment: Why? And also, I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manage all your domain names from one central location, you should set their NS records to point to the same two servers, e.g.

```
example.com.   NS   ns1.ab.com.
example.com.   NS   ns2.ab.com.
example.org.   NS   ns1.ab.com.
example.org.   NS   ns2.ab.com.
mydomain.int.  NS   ns1.ab.com.
mydomain.int.  NS   ns2.ab.com.
ab.com.        NS   ns1.ab.com.
ab.com.        NS   ns2.ab.com.
```

So update all the NS records in the different control panels from the registrars. Then you can create `zone`s of type `master` for each domain on ns1.ab.com or ns2.ab.com. The other name server will have `zone`s of type `slave` and fetch the config from the first name server.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is directly against [IANA Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements).

> **Consistency between delegation and zone**
>
> The set of `NS` records served by the authoritative name servers must
>   match those proposed for the delegation in the parent zone.

This is not possible, because DNS doesn't work like that. You can delegate subzones, though.

Comment: And how can I delegate the subzones? Can you link me to an answered post/

Comment: By a) pointing `sub.example.com. NS` to somewhere else and b) having `sub.example.com.` authoritative zone there. But that probably isn't what you are looking for here, anyway.